# Summernote - Insert template with angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, directive, summernote

I am planning to create a text editor, where users can build their own html pages by using AngularJS directives. I've found out about the summernote template plugin (https://github.com/Nanakii/summernote-plugins/tree/master/plugin/template), which works great for regular html, but doesn't correctly insert the AngularJS directives that contain given parameters.

Here's a small plunker project that demonstrates the issue. I've used both the original and angularjs-wrap summernotes and you can see the different behaviour. My aim is to be able to insert "Template 1" in such a way that it shows the given data (StringData and ObjectValue)

https://plnkr.co/edit/asKUJj2Mg4HnMASVHV7f?p=info

Index.html - General angular syntax works, as well as directive

```
  <div id="summernote">
      <h3>Using jQuery</h3>
      {{2+2}}
      {{testFromCtrl}}
      <mydirective vdata="StringData" vobj="{value: 'Object Value'}"></mydirective>
  </div>
```

However, once I try using the template insert system the **vdata** and **vobj** attributes are not shown. Also, I created a controller for the template1.html file and data from the controller isn't shown.

Template1.html

```
{{testFromCtrl}} My Directive:
 <mydirective vdata="StringData" vobj="{value: 'Object Value'}"></mydirective>
</div>
```

TemplateCtrl.js

```
app.controller("TemplateCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.testFromCtrl = "TestFromCtrl Approved";
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I decided not to use the summernote-template plugin and implement my own way of inserting templates, using angular. Therefore, I created a directive that would be a button that inserted a given template.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.userItems.insert', 
['oitozero.ngSweetAlert'])


.directive("fccpinsert", [ '$parse', 'SweetAlert', '$timeout' , function($parse, SweetAlert) {
var template = 
'<button class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" ng-click="insert($event)">Insert directive</button>';


return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        vdata:'='
    },
    template: template,

    controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', '$element', function($scope, $http, $compile, $element) {

        // Root path towards templates folder
        $scope.prefix = "views/summernote/tpls/";

        // Inserts directive into the text field
        $scope.insert = function(event){
            var filename = "template1";

            var path = $scope.prefix + filename + ".html";

            // If template is found
            var successCallback = function(response){

                var tpl = $compile(response.data)( $scope );
                console.log(tpl);

                $element.append(tpl);

                //class is : note-editable panel-body
                var documentResult = document.getElementsByClassName("note-editable panel-body");
                console.log('document.getElementsByClassName: ', documentResult);

                var wrappedDocumentResult = angular.element(documentResult);
                console.log('angular.element: ', wrappedDocumentResult);

                wrappedDocumentResult.append(tpl);


            };  

            var errorCallback = function(response){
                console.log(response);
                SweetAlert.swal("File not found", response.config.url + ": " + response.data, "error");
            };

            $http.get(path, {}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);




        };
    }],

    link: function($scope, $element){
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the question of "Summernote - Insert template with angular directives".**

My use case was to set a template (HTML code) in Summernote that had an AngularJS directive within the body of the template. The directive is **ng-repeat** that loops through a dynamic variable.

The problem is that Summernote does not compile AngularJs code.

My solution then was to compile the template to be used in Summernote, outside of the editor,and then use the id of the outer most  tag to pull in the compiled code into summernote.

With this I used an **ng-hide** directive so that the template is compiled on the DOM but just not shown. (dont use ng-if as it does not load on the DOM) .

For example:

HTML

```
         <div ng-hide="hideAccepted" id="letterAccepted">
           <div ng-repeat="object in clauseIdPayload.combinedIDs track by $index> {{object}}</div>
</div>
```

On initiation of the page set the hide to false and once
JS

```
   $scope.html = document.getElementById("letterAccepted");
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $note = $('.summernote-container').summernote({
                height: 500,
                callbacks: {
                    onChange: function (code, $editable) {
                        console.log('onChange:', code);

                        $scope.outcome.html = code;

                        $scope.outcome.html.toString();
                    }
                },
                toolbar: [
                    ['style', ['style']],
                    ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'clear']],
                    ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                    ['color', ['color']],
                    ['para', ['ol', 'ul', 'paragraph', 'height']],
                    ['table', ['table']],
                    ['view', ['undo', 'redo', 'codeview']]
                ]
            });



            $note.summernote('code', $scope.html);


        });
        // SUMMERNOTE
```

To solve the above problem, you could create a template selection outside of summernote and based on that condition assign to the $scope.html (if -else statements) variable I used above. For example

```
  if($scope.tpaInstructionsPayload.claimOutcome === 'Approved'){
            console.log("accepted")
            $scope.html = document.getElementById("letterAccepted");
     
        } else if($scope.tpaInstructionsPayload.claimOutcome === 'Partial Approved') {
            console.log("partial")

            $scope.html = document.getElementById("letterPartial");
           
        }else {
            $scope.html = document.getElementById("letterDeny");
           


        }
```